# Add new field with value from existing field in Logstash

Tags: json, logstash, grok

I have this log with message field contains this line

```
"message":"name="Alert notification" event_id=123 alert_name="alert 1234" ipaddr="192.168.0.1" object_name="localhost.local""
```

I want to add new field with the value after = sign so it will look like this

```
"alert_name":"alert 1234",
"object_name":"localhost.local",
"ipaddr":"192.168.0.1"
```

I've tried using this kind of grok filter but it grab the whole string **("alert_name":"alert_name"="alert 1234")**

```
grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{WORD:method1} %{WORD:method2} %{WORD:method3}" }
      }
```

How to only pass value after = to this new field?

Comment: Why use grok instead of a kv filter?

Comment: You are correct. KV filter is the way to go. Thanks!!